# How to model semi-financial transactions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to model a Transaction (nothing to do with SQL transaction), which is "responsible" for these use cases:

- a user can deposit money on his prepaid account
- a user can also withdraw from that same account
- a user can send money (for a favor) to another user

One suggestion is to use the following attributes on the Transaction model: sender_id, receiver_id and favor_id. In this case, the first two use cases would have one of the fields that relate to user (sender_id and receiver_id) and favor_id set to nil, which kinda defeats the purpose of belongs_to (Transaction belongs to receiver, sender and favor). Here's the snippet for this version:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :sender, :receiver, :favor, :amount

  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :favor, :foreign_key => "favor_id"

  scope :of_user, lambda { |user_id|
    where("sender_id = ? or receiver_id = ?", user_id,  user_id)
  }

  scope :external_of_user, lambda { |user_id|
    where("(sender_id = ? AND receiver_id IS NULL) or (receiver_id = ? AND sender_id IS NULL)", user_id,  user_id)
  }

end
```

The second suggestion would be to use user_id on each Transaction, but in that case, every transaction between two users would create two records, first belonging to sender and having negative number, while second belonging to receiver and having a positive number. In this case, existence of favor_id would indicate whether it was deposit/withdrawal or paying for a favor.

Which of these two sound more reasonable?

Comment: Are your favors always have a reward associated with them?

Comment: What is the point of favors here? Why is it a field for transaction? Genuine question. What if I just want to send money to someone and its not a favor, but a debt?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :favor
  has_one :recipient, :through => :favor
end

class Favor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transaction
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Comment: cheers, used this one with some small modifications (based on the comment from Matzi) but it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience in financial applications. In that system we used "two legs" for the two sides of the transaction. One leg had a negative amount and the other had a positive depending on the direction, also a financial transaction held the two together. This way you can easily summarize the legs on an account without having to bother with the other sides. Seems a bit redundant (it is), but it is more like the old book keeping customs, and you can more easily summarize as you don't need to decide the direction based on that if a user is on the sending or the receiving side of the deal. You can easily model deposit and withdrawal trough a one-legged transaction when money misteriously appears in the system.

By the way, you sould not use Users in this. Use accounts as Users can share accounts (eg. companies) and any User may have multiple accounts. And of course the user is not really interesting, all that matters is the money.